# how to download remote binary file into char array in curl using c++?

Tags: c++, curl

I have a binary file in a remote web server.

And I want to download it with curl in c++.

But in one condition, I cannot write it to a file.

So I have to hold it into char array.

What I have tried so far is,

```
size_t WriteHtmlCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream)
{
    ((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size * count);

    return size * count;
}

std::string html;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteHtmlCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &html);
```

But html string loses binary data.

What's the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [libcurl output to variable instead of textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020640/libcurl-output-to-variable-instead-of-textfile)

Comment: Although the answer I flagged as duplicate isn't a perfect match, I believe you'll find the answer there.

Comment: @jpw Actually, it was quite good example for me. Writing it into stringstream, but the result looks the same. Anyway, thanks a lot.